# MNIST with TensorFlow-Inputs to a layer should be tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist

I'm trying to exercise the TensorFlow Deep Convolutional Generative Adversarial Network based on the MNIST database. In order to test my coding abilities I downloaded the MNIST database directly from there website(instead of `tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()`) and I have the following problem during executing the following line:
`real_output = discriminator(images, training=True)`
The error:

````
        raise TypeError('Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: %s' % (x,))
    TypeError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got: pixel0```
What should I do to solve this?
````

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it.
The solution is to normalize the images to values in the range -1 to 1:
train_images = (train_images - 127.5) / 127.5 # Normalize the images to [-1, 1]